# What do I do for edits on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, closed-questions

While reviewing I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6377983) suggested edit. The edit wasn't horrible, but I realized the question was not right.

Once I dug deeper, I saw the question had been closed. What should I do about edits like this? Sure, if they added a period at the end it would be a little nicer, but should we be editing questions that are closed?

Comment: Well, did rearranging all the words like that improve that question at all? I don't think it did.

Comment: *This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.* or *This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.*

Comment: No, I guess not. It helped improve the grammar and presentation of the question, but it is still off topic for the site. So I guess I'm asking if I should let the question interfere with how I treat the edit?

Comment: I don't feel like it improved the grammar. It changed the author's intent, too. From just looking at source code (implicitly to use), versus creating your own and needing examples.

Answer (score 7):

The question is entirely unsalvageable *after the edit*.  As such, the edit is adding no value at all.

If the edit was either turning the question into one that would no longer merit closure, or at least bringing it into a place where it's both noticeably improved and *is salvageable into a decent question after the edit* then its adding value.

We don't want people going around polishing turds; it's not a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: So would this be a reject as 'no improvement whatsoever', in your opinion?

Comment: @McAdam331 I would.  Using "other" to explain that the post isn't salvageable even after the edit would also be acceptable.